# Variable column output

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, loops, while-loop, case

Can I use a loop to create a variable number of columns based on a calculation?

Table A: has columns id, name, date, item. It shows who bought an item on what day. name appears multiple times any time an item is bought. id is unique.

Table B: has name, begindate. It shows when name started working.

(I know how to associate name with begindate, so it's not really in the pseudo code below.)

Table C is what I want my results to look like:

```
name   itemsday1 itemsday2 itemsday3... itemsdayn
```

the 2nd column correspends to items bought today, the last cloumn to items bought on of before name's begindate. The number of columns needs to vary based on the person who started the earliest. I want my query to loop and create a column for each day from begindate until today, where it counts the number of items bought by Name that day.

Psuedo code:

```
declare mostd INT
select datediff(dd, begindate, getdate()) as spans  into #span from B
set mostd = select max(spans) from #span

select
    name
    ,while mostd !=0
        begin
            case when???
                count(items)
            end as column.mostd
            mostd=mostd-1
        end
    end
from A (join B blah blah)
group by name

Results
NAME    column4    column3    column2    column1    column0
James   9          8          7          6          NULL
Wade    5          4          3          NULL       NULL
Bosh    2          1          NULL       NULL       NULL
Durant  0          9          8          NULL       NULL
```

Can TSQL do this? Can you hep me solidify this into real code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using the PIVOT operator http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

UPDATE: An example. It is inspired by this great article: http://dotnetgalactics.wordpress.com/2009/10/23/using-sql-server-20052008-pivot-on-unknown-number-of-columns-dynamic-pivot/:

```
-- create table #items (id int, name varchar(40), date datetime, userid int)
-- create table #users (id int, name varchar(40), begindate datetime)

declare @dates varchar(4000)
declare @query varchar(4000)

SELECT  @dates = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT
                        '],[' + cast(date as varchar(30))
                        FROM    #items
                        ORDER BY '],[' + cast(date as varchar(30))
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                        ), 1, 2, '') + ']'

set @query = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT #users.name, date FROM #items
        INNER JOIN #users ON #items.userid = #users.id) items 
        PIVOT (COUNT(date) FOR date IN (' + @dates + ')) pvt'

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Result:

```
name  2012-10-01 2012-10-02 2012-10-03 2012-10-04 2012-10-05 2012-10-06 2012-10-07

user1     0          0           1          0          0          1         0
user2     1          6           0          0          0          1         1
user3     1          1           7          0          0          3         0
user4     0          0           0          1          1          1         1
```

Comment: Could you help me visualize this? Are you saying a PIVOT on my original table (Table A: id,name,date,item) can rotate to make c columns for each day, rows for name, and aggregates where those meet? For some reason, base don the example in the link, I fee like the format might not fit. I'll try this though thanks.

Comment: Done. You just need to match the joins.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use dynamic SQL to do this. Start with

```
DECLARE @SelectSQL varchar(max) = "SELECT name";
```

Then do your while loop, tracking an integer counter for the field name (if you really want to do this in reverse order, you'll need to use DATEDIFF(day, getdate(), begindate) and count backwards). For each day you want a column representing, output the following:

```
SELECT @SelectSQL = @SelectSQL + ', (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM TableA where name = TableB.name AND [date] = ''' + CONVERT(varchar, @mostd) + ''') AS column' + str(@ColumnCounter)
```

Then, outside of the loop, you postpend the rest of the query:

```
@SelectSQL = @SelectSQL + ' FROM TableB';
```

Note, no join to TableA because that is all taken care of in the subqueries. Also, for the same reason, you don't need `GROUP BY.`

**Edit:** Whoops, forgot the last part.

To execute this, just run:

```
EXEC (@SelectSQL);
```

Comment: Wow. I've never heard of dynamic SQL. I'll see what I can read on this. My current skill isn't on that level. It looks like a really compact solution though. Thanks.

Comment: The code above isn't the only way to do this-- @Tisho proposed the PIVOT method, which can also create columns from row data. But even that doesn't work on an arbitrary number of columns, or for arbitrary values. So in order to make that work you still need to fall back to dynamic SQL to generate the PIVOT. Basically, SQL just doesn't like (for good reason, in general) to return data without a predefined shape (number/type of columns, etc.), and you usually need to resort to dynamic SQL in order to make it do so.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few answers on SO relating to dynamically pivoting data - this is one I provided, and it is a useful thing to know.

[sql server 2008 dynamic pivot based on ordinal value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022742/sql-server-2008-dynamic-pivot-based-on-ordinal-value/7144869#7144869)

By using the XML PATH operator, you also get decent column names in your resultset.